# Spotfire - Iron python Script to get details of all tables and columns used in report

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer, ironpython-studio

I am searching for a iron python script to get details of all tables and columns used in the entire report. It would also be great if i can also get the Information Links used in the report.

Thanks in advance

I searched online but did not find anything.